# Table relationship

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, entity-relationship

if I have below relationship table, which one is correct ?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: What does "correct" mean?

Comment: correct here, I means which one is the right way or best practice in database

Comment: My current generic comment re "better"/"best" etc: There's no such thing as "better"/"best" in engineering unless *you* define it. Also unfortunately all reasonable practical definitions require a ridiculous amount of experience with a ridiculous number of factors that interact with chaotic sensitivity to details. Make straightforward designs. When you demonstrate via measurement that a design and all alternatives you can think of have problems (whatever that means at the time), then ask a very specific question. Which should also define "better"/"best". https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. Use edit functions to inline, not link, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained. And never give a diagram without a legend/key.

Comment: What is the modeling/design reference you are supposed to use? Time to read a textbook introducing information modeling & information design to find out what tables are for & what constraints are for. Give all constraints that hold on possible situations & the meaning of each base table--what a row says about the situation when in it. Otherwise we don't know enough to give any design let alone a beginner's "better" one. Eg you probably want course-student id pairs to be unique & attendance id pairs to be unique & to maybe to appear in course_student etc--but we don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Probably neither. For one thing, surrogate keys in association tables is an anti-pattern. B is better than A, but too complicated.

You probably need only one association table, with course_id, student_id and date. Assuming each student can attend many courses and each course can be attended by many students, its key is either { course_id, student_id }, if each student can attend each course at most once; or { course_id, student_id, date } if each student can attend each course many times at different dates.

(If each student can attend each course multiple times on the same date, we need more info.)

Comment: Sort of, but I have multiple issues with your answer. Faced with the options of editing your answer to my liking (too drastic/impolite), convincing you through comments to change it (too uncertain and time-consuming) and formulating my own short answer, I chose the latter option.

Comment: No, no. My changing it would be too drastic/impolite, as I would have to do major changes.